# Unable to get User angular 2(Authentication credentials were not provided)

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to get user information thorugh a get request from my angular service in following way.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {homeUrls} from "../../../utils/urls";
import {Http, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class AdsService {
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private token: string;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log("token is " , this.token);
    this.headers.set('Authorization', 'Token ' + this.token );
    console.log("header is");
    console.log(this.headers);
    this.getMe();
  }

  getMe(): Promise<any> {
      return this.http.get(homeUrls.User, {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res=> {
          console.log("user is");
          console.log(res.json());
        })

  }
```

but i am getting following error

**failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/account/me/: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.**

when i check in network tab it says "authentication credentials were not provided", although i have set the authorization header as it can be seen in my service's constructor. Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Headers is an immutable object. The set and append methods don't modify the Headers object, they return a new Object.

Also, you probably want to use append rather than set.

Comment: i have used append as well, but same reponse, "Authentication credentials were not provided"

Comment: make sure that you do `headers = headers.append(...)` , so that you get the new value

Comment: i have done that, but same response, although when i do the same request with postman it is giving correct response, so it means problem lies at angular side,

Comment: in request  headers: Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type